# Windows 8 handling untrusted certificates

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have seen many questions about this, and answers:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

But it doesn't add usings.

I'm writing a windows 8 project, not windows 8.1

But all documents say that supported platforms are: Windows 8
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.security.protectionlevel(v=vs.110).aspx

Is there any workaround for this? In windows 8.0?

Because it means that our app won't run on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows 8, there are two cases.

Your certificate is known: you can add the certificate to the application and add [a declaration to the package manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465031.aspx)

You need to trust unknown certificates, you'll need a custom SSL/TLS implementation. For instance you can use [WinRT Bouncy Castle](https://w8bouncycastle.codeplex.com/). There are several way to support untrusted certificates. The easier way is to implement a custom ICertificateVerifyer and connect with a TlsProtocolHandler on top of a regular WinRT plain socket:

```
        this.port = port;
        host = new Windows.Networking.HostName(hostName);

        socket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();

        await socket.ConnectAsync(host, port.ToString(), Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);
        handler = new TlsProtocolHandler(socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead(), socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite());
        handler.Connect(certificateVerifyer);
```